# Add Custom Data Type/Field in Jaydata

Tags: jaydata

How can I add a custom data type in Jaydata wherein I can just add anything on it and have it output in **http://localh.ost/blahblah/$metadata** ?
Like

```
$data.Entity.extend("Office", {
    Id: { type: "id", key: true, computed: true },
    OfficeName: { type: "string", maxLength:50, alternativeName:"office_name" }
});
```

Like I want to add the **alternativeName** and have it output in the browser so that when I type the **http://localh.ost/blahblah/$metadata**, I can see it as one of the fields.
Like:

```
//other XML output here
<Property MaxLength="50" Name="OffName" Type="Edm.String" alternativeName="office_name"/>
//other XML output here
```

Right now, I can only see this:

```
<Property MaxLength="50" Name="OffName" Type="Edm.String" />
```

So how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Start the custom attribute name with $ sign